# Time complexity for the Nested Loops

Tags: python, algorithm, data-structures, time-complexity

I have a program below which calculates the Maximum Pairwise Product.

```
for i in range(n):
    for j in range(i + 1, n):
        product = max(product, a[i] * a[j])
```

As per my calculation the above program takes (n^2 - n) steps where n is the number of elements but the book I am following it says n^2 steps.
Can anyone help me in understanding which is right?

Comment: You are both right. But your calculation is not complete: `n^2-n` is of `O(n^2)` complexity.

Comment: Thank you for your comments @MichaelSzczesny. Can you please elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is a plain English explanation of "Big O" notation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When dealing with the Big O notation you always take the largest power terms - the logic is simple - as n grows larger n^2 is going to grow quicker than n and therefore the growth rate of the time will be dominated by n^2.

Therefore the correct big O is O(n^2)

Answer (score 2):

In Big O Notation, the Maximum Degree term of the equation is considered only.
For eg,

1)**n+7** - here we will consider n only so **O of n** is the time complexity.

2)**n^2 + n + 3** - here we will consider n^2 only so **O of n^2** is the time complexity.

3)**3x(n^2)** - here we will consider n^2 only so **O of n^2** is the time complexity.

As big O notation is the approximate time complexity, we neglect all the small terms.

For your equation **n^2 - n**

Consider **n** as **10000**

**n^2 = 100000000**

**n^2 - n = 99990000**.  Which is nearly equal to **100000000 i.e n^2**

so we consider the highest degree term only. Therefore time complexity is **O(n^2)**